# angular2 new router will not load 2 components (head & content) simultaneously on page load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

My Angular2 beta.0 test app has a HeaderFooter app that appears on page load. In between the header and the footer is a content section. 1st problem: I want the content section to load with the Home component on the same page load event with the HeaderFooter component. After a lot of research and thrashing, it still doesn't show both components on load. 2nd problem: I can get the test Home content to appear by clicking a link in the header, and it routes forward to another test page. It does not route backwards reliably and the browser back and forward buttons do not route reliably, i.e., 2 steps is OK, 3 steps is not. Here's relevant code:

index.html

```
<div>
  <residence-app><h1>Loading . . .</h1></residence-app>
</div>
```

boot.ts - this supposedly boots all components without individual component bootstraps.  When I put bootstraps in each component, I get Console errors about selectors, but they don't mean anything to me.

```
import { bootstrap }    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { HeaderFooter } from './app';
import { RouteConfig, Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router';
bootstrap( HeaderFooter, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ] );
```

app.ts

```
//various imports
@Component({
  selector: 'residence-app',
  templateUrl: "angular2-oPost/src/components/navigation/headerFooter.html",
  styleUrls: [ "angular2-oPost/src/commonStyles/headerFooter.css" ],
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Home, PostApartment4Rent ]
@RouteConfig( [
  new Route({ path: "/home", name: "Home", component: Home, useAsDefault: true }),
  new Route({ path: "/postApartment4Rent ",  name: "PostApartment4Rent", component: PostApartment4Rent })
] )
export class HeaderFooter { }
```

headerFooter.html

```
<header>
<!-- several divs-->
<a [routerLink]="['../Home']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['../PostApartment4Rent']">Rent Apartment in hF</a>
</header> 
<div class="partialPage">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<footer>
  <!-- several divs-->
</footer>
```

home.ts

```
@Component({
  selector : "home",
  styleUrls: [ "angular2-oPost/src/commonStyles/headerFooter.css" ],
  template: `
  <main>
    <h1>Home page map</h1>
  </main>
  `,
  directives: [ RouterLink ]
})
export class Home { }
```

postApartment4Rent.ts - is the same as home.ts, except for the selector in the @Component, the h1 text, and the class statement

```
selector: "postApartment4Rent",

export class PostApartment4Rent { }
```

Comment: don't do `"../Home"` in the routerLink, it expects the name of the route definition `new Route({ path: "/home", name: "Home"` in this case just `Home`

Comment: you are bootstraping directly to the header, bootstrap to an `app` component that includes both the header and the footer so you can see both.

Comment: Langley, thank you. I changed "../Home" to "Home" in the routerLinks. Everything works the same - no change in behavior. That seems odd since one way is a call to a file hierarchy and the other is a call to a component, but either way works. Re the second thought -  boot.ts shows that it bootstraps a component HeaderFooter from a file app.ts  HeaderFooter shows both header and footer on page load. My problem is that Home component does not show in between the header and footer at page load. I get only a blank from the div containing router-outlet in headerFooter.html

Comment: Are you writing it like this?: `<a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>` any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, its written exactly that way. There are no Console errors either way its written - with or without ../

Comment: is your url changing at all? you might want to use a plunker or a codepen with the issue happening so its easier to spot the error

Comment: Yes, the URL changes. But the primary issue is that the Home component does not show on page load of HeaderFooter. I get my nice header and footer and a gray background in between them.

Answer (score 0):

From reading and trying more tutorials, I changed the last line in `boot.ts` from:

```
bootstrap( HeaderFooter, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS ] );
```

to:

```
bootstrap( HeaderFooter, [ ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(LocationStrategy, 
    {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}) ] );
```

I also had to import provide from `angular2/core`.

On page load, the Home component now appears simultaneously between the header and footer from the HeaderFooter component.  Routing between pages is mostly OK, but unreliable using the browser back button. I'm going to let that go for now because I read the History API for browsers is unstable, at the moment.

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar problem. The router will load only the container component and will not load the child components. On a second attempt clicking the router link loads the components again.